# Best way to replace/publish the restructured website in SEO friendly manner

Tags: seo, google-search-console, redirects, subdomain, google-index

I had a website which contains several subdomains.

```
http://sub1.example.com/stories/23/job-done.html
http://sub2.example.com/stories/23/job-done.html
```

At present I decided to restructure my website to change all subdomains and links to a different structure like,

```
http://stories.example.com/23/job-done.html
```

**Both structures displays same content.**

Currently I am using Google Webmaster Tools and most of my webpages are indexed in Google and have some PageRank also.

Before publishing my restructured website, I thought about what are the options that I can preserve my Google rankings as:

- Remove whole old website and publish the restructured website and **do the relative changes in Webmaster Tools**
- Remove whole old website and publish the restructured website and **remove account and recreate new account in Webmaster Tools to restructured website**
- Publish restructured website **without removing old webpages** and **use 301 redirect on old pages to its related new webpage**.

So what is the best way to publish my restructured website from above options or do I need to do something else to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third option will be the option to consider here. A proper 301 redirect to the new content will let the crawlers know, that the content has moved. They will keep the page rank and move it to the new domain.

As far as your Webmaster Tools are concerned, you will have to use the [Change of Address](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106) tool, to let Google know, you moved your content. It is exactly, what you're looking for.

Google itself explains, [how to move a site properly](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83105?hl=en&ref_topic=2370420). It suggests the 301 redirect, too.

Comment: Thanks friend.I also thought it that way.And what about the webmaster tools? Because I have added all old sub-domains to webmaster account.Should I remove those?

Comment: I edited my answer, regarding your question about the webmaster tools.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with what the previous commenters have said. 
I would also recommend using an on-page checker (a http://www.w3.org/ checker or an seo site auditor http://www.link-assistant.com/website-auditor/) to check if the redirects are set up correctly. 
this will also show you what pages have canonical tags, special robots.txt instructions and other SEO-specific things you might overlook in the process of moving the site.

Answer (score 0):

Make a sitemap of the current page structure now, and do all 301 redirects for every page (*.htaccess*), quite easily since the structure is more or less the same.

And then make changes also in Webmaster Tools and resubmit new sitemap.

Comment: @ MP Thanks friend.Since my page links are dynamic according to contents,I can't go with htaccess.